# erroe in importing volley in project

Tags: android, android-volley

i am trying to import the volley in the android application.,an given in example Here's [a link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library)! and did all the steps it ask in the project,but iam getting error 'Method' cannote be resolve in line

JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener()

please help me to resolve it,what is the problem,i am not able to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the necessary tools to clone a project (Git).

**Cloning volley library**

Open command prompt, navigate to a location where you want to clone volley and execute following command. This will download a copy of volley library into your local drive.

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
```

See how integrate Volley in your project here: https://github.com/smanikandan14/Volley-demo
  and here : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/